# Cycling through a date

Tags: python

I have defined day and month in a previous part of the code. I need this program to run when day is less than 7. I am asking for an input of spendings in the last 7 days.

The problem: If the input of day is 4, for example, 4 - 4(days) is day 0 (does not exist), 4 - 5 is day -1, 4 - 6 is day -2, 4 - 7 is day -3. I need it to be day 4 - 4 = 31 or 30 or 28 or 29 (that is already defined), 4 - 5 = 30, 4 - 6 = 29.

I know that this is poorly structured, I apologize, English is not my first language. Will try to make it clear if it is not understood like this.

```
listOfSpendings = []
x = 0
while x < 7:
    if day - x <=0:
        month = month - 1
        dayDiff= ###SOMETHING I DUNNOOOO
        day = monthlenght - dayDiff
    print ("How many liters did you spend on the day", day - x, "of", month)
    spendings = input()
    while True:
        try:
            spendings = int(spendings)
            if spendings < 0:
                spendings = input ("Insert a value =! 0")
            else:
                break
        except ValueError:
            spendings = input("Incorrect value, correct")
    x = x+1
    listOfSpendings.append(spendings)

sumSpendings = sum (listOfSpendings)
```

Comment: Just try using the datetime library, that will handle that kind of operations for you

Comment: My problem with that library is that it is almost exclusively related to operations between dd-mm-yyyy (*,/,+,-) dd-mm-yyyy...

Comment: I'd suggest using some modular arithmetic. Aka the % operator. Example usage: `-1 % 30 = 29`

Comment: @Charlie That is a great idea! Just can't figure out the value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as it is will run into negative numbers with months as well.  Using the datetime library that was suggested you can do the following:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

list_of_spendings = []

# Month number
for day in [(datetime.now()-timedelta(x)) for x in range(7)]:
    print('How many liters did you spend on the day {} of {}'.format(day.day, day.month))
    #Rest of your code
```

OR

```
# Month name
for day in [(datetime.now()-timedelta(x)) for x in range(7)]:
    print('How many liters did you spend on the day {} of {}'.format(day.day, day.strftime('%B')))
    #Rest of your code
```

OR

```
# Short month name
for day in [(datetime.now()-timedelta(x)) for x in range(7)]:
    print('How many liters did you spend on the day {} of {}'.format(day.day, day.strftime('%b')))
    #Rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I figured it out. "Dia" and "mes" are previously defined.

Translations:

```
listaGastos = listOfSpendings
gastos = spendings
dia = day
mes = month
DuracMes = monthlenght
diaC = currentDay
mesC = currentMonth
```

Code:

```
DuracMes = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
listaGastos = []
x = 0
diaC = dia
mesC = mes
while x < 7:
    dia = diaC - x
    if dia <= 0:
        mes = mesC - 1
        diaDif = diaC - 1
        dia = DuracMes [mes - 1] + dia
    print("Quantos litros de soro fisiologico foram gastos no dia", dia, "de", mes)
    gastos = input()
    while True:
        try:
            gastos = int (gastos)
            if gastos < 0:
                gastos = input ("Introduza um valor diferente de 0: ")
            else:
                break
        except ValueError:
            gastos = input ("Nao inseriu um valor adequado, quantos litros de soro fisiologico foram gastos nos ultimos sete dias? ")
    x += 1
    listaGastos.append(gastos)

sumGastos = sum (listaGastos)
```